# Changing title text in SharePoint top navigation bar using TypeScript/JSOM

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, jsom, typescript, top-navigation

I'm trying to change the title of the **first** item in the top navigation bar in a SharePoint 2019 modern site. The code is run in a TypeScript web part.

My code below runs fine and no errors are reported, but the text in the top nav is never changed. Can anyone please help me to see what I have overlooked?

```
public editMainNavigation(newTitle: string, siteUrl: string) {
  const context: SP.ClientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
  const web: SP.Web = context.get_web();

  const topNavBar: SP.NavigationNodeCollection = web.get_navigation().get_topNavigationBar();
  context.load(topNavBar);
  context.executeQueryAsync((sender: any, args: SP.ClientRequestSucceededEventArgs): void => {
    console.log('current title', topNavBar.get_item(0).get_title());
    console.log('new title to set', newTitle);
    topNavBar.get_item(0).set_title(newTitle); // <-- Setting new title to the first item
    context.load(topNavBar);
    context.executeQueryAsync(() => {
      console.log(`Title for main project in global navigation is now ${newTitle}.`);
    }, (args: SP.ClientRequestFailedEventArgs): void => {
      console.log('Nope!', args);
    });
  });
}
```

This is what is logged to the console:

```
current title My title before
new title to set My title after
Title for main project in global navigation is now My title after.
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find a solution on how to update the title, so I delete the links and recreate them instead. Here's my solution if anyone is interested.

Not my best work, but that will have to do for now.

```
interface ISites {
  Title: string;
  URL: string;
}

public static editMainNavigation(newTitle: string, siteUrl: string) {
  const context: SP.ClientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
  const web: SP.Web = context.get_web();
  const topNavBar: SP.NavigationNodeCollection = web.get_navigation().get_topNavigationBar();
  context.load(topNavBar);
  context.executeQueryAsync((sender: any, args: SP.ClientRequestSucceededEventArgs): void => {
    const list: ISites[] = [];
    const nodeEnumerator = topNavBar.getEnumerator();
    while (nodeEnumerator.moveNext()) {
      const node = nodeEnumerator.get_current();
      list.push({
        Title: node.get_title(),
        URL: node.get_url()
      });
    }

    /* It didn't work to update the title, so I put all links in a list and manipulate the list instead.
       I then remove all the links in the navbar and use the list to replace the content.
       1. Replace the main project title in the list with the new title. The list is now finished.
       2. Delete all links.
       3. Iterate through the list and add every item as a new link.
    */

    // 1.
    if (list.length > 0) {
      list[0].Title = newTitle;
    }

    // 2.
    while (topNavBar.get_count() > 0) {
      topNavBar.get_item(0).deleteObject();
    }

    // 3.
    list.forEach((navItem) => {
      const newNavItem = new SP.NavigationNodeCreationInformation();
      newNavItem.set_title(navItem.Title);
      newNavItem.set_url(navItem.URL);
      newNavItem.set_asLastNode(true); // Put the new link at the end of the line
      topNavBar.add(newNavItem);
    });

    context.load(topNavBar);
    context.executeQueryAsync(() => {
      console.log(`Title for main project in global navigation is now ${newTitle}.`);
    }, (args: SP.ClientRequestFailedEventArgs): void => {
      console.error(`Could not change title to ${newTitle} for main project in global navigation.\n${args}`);
    });
  });
}
```